# How to make flexible enough a function that return a plot?

Tags: python, function, matplotlib

I want to create a function that returns a matplotlib plot. It should have some defined parameters like scale, color and ticks, but I’d like the function to be flexible enough for either modifying or adding plot parameters.

```
def foo(x,y,*arg,**kwarg)
    ax=plt.gca()
    ax.plot(x,y,**kwarg)
    ax.xaxis.set_scale(“log”)
*arg
```

I don't know this is the right way for adding or modifying parameters without explicitly writing them on the function input

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you define "*flexible enough*"? You have some vague requirements for this function, do you only want scale, color, and ticks to be modifiable?

Comment: Your current code allows to for the flexibility you ask for. Since matplotlib cannot guess what scale, color and ticks you want, you will need to specify them *somewhere*, either in the function, or when calling the function.